# Marcação de página

Tags: php

Estou tentando criar um campo de marcação de página de livro, mas não estou sabendo relacionar tabelas. Criei 3 tabelas Usuário, Título e Páginas. Eu até consegui relacionar com o usuário com *cookie*, mas não estou conseguindo pensar em um jeito de relacionar a id do título.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<?php
$login_cookie = $_COOKIE['login'];
    if (!isset($login_cookie)) {
      header("Location: index.php");
    }

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'lista');
$paginas = $_POST["paginas"];
$ins = "INSERT INTO paginas (paginas, usuario) VALUES ('".$paginas."','".$login_cookie."')";


if(mysqli_query($con, $ins)) {

echo "Registrado com sucesso!";

} else {
    echo "Erro ao registrar!";
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
 ?>
```

Comment: Não acho que valha a pena colocar tudo em cookie.

Comment: De onde vem a ID do título?

Comment: A id do título ainda n coloquei, pq não sabia como inserir ela. mas ela seria idtitulo.